# Ayuda con ejercicio en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente ejercicio:
Es un ejercicio usando JS en la consola del navegador,tengo 3 cartas,tengo que crear una funcion y sumarlas con la siguiente condicion,si la carta es un 1 vale 20 y si es una carta roja vale el doble de su valor.

```js
carta1 = {PALO:"c",VALOR:1}
carta2 = {PALO:"d",VALOR:7}
carta3 = {PALO:"p",VALOR:5}
cartas = [carta1,carta2,carta3];

function puntua(){
  var mano = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {
    if (cartas[i].VALOR === 1) {
        cartas[i].VALOR = 20;
    }
    if (cartas[i].PALO === "d" || cartas[i].PALO === "c") {
        cartas[i].VALOR = cartas[i].VALOR*2;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i ++) {   
        mano = mano + cartas[i].VALOR;
    }
   
  }
  console.log(mano);
}

puntua();
```

como resultado me da 52, yo supongo que el 1 de corazones me lo esta dando como 40 ya que el 1 vale 20 y al ser roja vale el doble, pero no se porque las otras 2 cartas me las suma solo como 5 y 7 cuando el 7 que es un "d" me lo tendria que sumar como 14,alguien puede decirme que ve mal en mi codigo

Comment: Usar la variable i, en dos for anidados es mala idea. La variable que usas en el segundo for, llamala de otra manera.

Comment: @Fernando Tema aparte: tienes bastantes preguntas hechas, estaría bien que *aceptases* alguna de las respuestas si consideras que te han sido útiles para que la pregunta quede marcada como *respondida*

Comment: No se como hacerlo @Pablo Lozano, me gustaria poder aceptar la repuesta que me vino mejor o resulto mejor o poder dar como cerrada la pregunta pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Al lado de cada respuesta, debajo de los botones de borrar, hay un *check* o palomita. Si pulsas sobre ella, aceptas esa respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de que no te funcione bien, tienes otro problema: estás modificando el valor de las cartas, lo que deberías evitar: Si quieres comprobar el valor dos veces, la segunda vez volverá a multiplicar por dos el valor de las cartas rojas.

Usando la estrategia *divide y vencerás*, puedes crear primero una función que te calcule el valor de una carta sin modificarla y luego usarla para sumar un conjunto de cartas.

En mi solución estoy usando el método `Array.reduce()` por lo simple que queda, ahorrándote hasta los bucles:

```js
let carta1 = {PALO:"c",VALOR:1}
let carta2 = {PALO:"d",VALOR:7}
let carta3 = {PALO:"p",VALOR:5}
let cartas = [carta1,carta2,carta3];

function puntuaCarta(c) {
  let v = c.VALOR === 1 ? 20: c.VALOR;
  if (c.PALO === 'c' || c.PALO === 'd') {
    v = v * 2; //duplicamos
  }
  console.log('Vale',v);
  return v;
}

function puntua(cartas){
  return cartas.reduce(
    (acumulador,c ) => acumulador + puntuaCarta(c), //función que acumula
    0 //valor inicial del acumulador
  );
}

console.log('Puntuación',puntua(cartas));
```

Pero si quieres un clásico bucle (totalmente válido, es cuestión de gustos), puedes hacerlo así:

```js
let carta1 = {PALO:"c",VALOR:1}
let carta2 = {PALO:"d",VALOR:7}
let carta3 = {PALO:"p",VALOR:5}
let cartas = [carta1,carta2,carta3];

function puntuaCarta(c) {
  let v = c.VALOR === 1 ? 20: c.VALOR;
  if (c.PALO === 'c' || c.PALO === 'd') {
    v = v * 2; //duplicamos
  }
  console.log('Vale',v);
  return v;
}

function puntua(cartas){
  var mano = 0;
  for (let i=0;i<cartas.length;i++) {
    mano+=puntuaCarta(cartas[i]);
  }
  return mano;
}

console.log('Puntuación',puntua(cartas));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo arregle espero te funcione, tenias un ciclo **for** que no debía estar.

```js
carta1 = {PALO:"c",VALOR:1}
carta2 = {PALO:"d",VALOR:7}
carta3 = {PALO:"p",VALOR:5}
cartas = [carta1,carta2,carta3];

function puntua(){
  var mano = 0;
  cartas.forEach(function(elemento) {
    var carta = elemento.VALOR == 1 ? 20 : elemento.VALOR;
    if (elemento.PALO == "d" || elemento.PALO == "c")
      carta = carta * 2;
    console.log(carta);
    mano += carta;
  });
  console.log(mano);
}
puntua();
```

Comment: El problema es que esta solución modifica el valor de las cartas, si llamas dos veces a `puntua()` dará valores distintos.

Comment: Si tienes razón en cada iteración le asigna un valor nuevo a las cartas.

Comment: Ya lo arregle amigo gracias por la observación.